# How to convert bibtex references to footnotes

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, footnotes, conversion

I have a LaTeX file and a bibtex file using the natbib package for bibliography management. I wanted to convert this to HTML using https://github.com/softcover/softcover . However softcover does not support bibtex and bibliographies in general. The author recommends to use footnotes instead. But this means, that I have to convert all `\cite` into corresponding `\footnote` commands.

Because doing this manually is really a lot of work, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this conversion automatically. Basically I want to convert the following two files

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
This document is an example of bibliography 
management\footnote{We are using the \texttt{natbib} package.}. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the \citet{einstein} journal paper, and the 
Donald Knuth's website \citep{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are
\cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{natbib}

\end{document}
```

and

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    Note    = "URL: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html",
    year    = "1999"
}
```

into one file using the `\footnote` command instead of `\cite` commands of natbib like

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
This document is an example of bibliography 
management\footnote{We are not using the \texttt{natbib} package.}. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book\footnote{Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., and Samarin, A. (1993). Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts.}, 
the\footnote{Einstein, A. (1905).{\em Annalen der Physik}, 322(10):891--921} 
journal paper, and the Donald Knuth's website\footnote{Knuth, D. (1999). URL: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html.}. 
The \LaTeX\ related items are\footnote{Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., and Samarin, A. (1993). Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts., Knuth, D. (1999). URL: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html.}. 

\end{document}
```

I generated the latter file manually by copying the content of the references from the `.bbl` file into the `\footnote` commands. With many references this becomes very tedious and errorprone. Is there a way to do such a conversion programmatically?

Comment: You might find `pandoc` gives you more flexibility. In terms of getting the references right, you might want to switch the `.bst` involved. `pandoc` is supposed to work with both traditional BibTeX and the more modern `biblatex`.

Comment: Is there any news here?